# WindowChrome - How to modify or disable context menu in the title bar?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I need to disable context menu in the title bar in the WPF window which uses WindowChrome:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="35"
                      CornerRadius="0"
                      ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                      UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
</Window>
```

ContextMenu="{x:Null}" doesn't work.
The following instructions don't work too:
http://codereply.com/answer/7etz8e/remove-title-bars-context-menu-completely-wpf-window.html
The context menu in the title bar appears always with no change.
Somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr windowhandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowhandle);
        hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    private const uint WM_SYSTEMMENU = 0xa4;
    private const uint WP_SYSTEMMENU = 0x02;

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if ((msg == WM_SYSTEMMENU) && (wParam.ToInt32() == WP_SYSTEMMENU))
        {
            handled = true;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be better when you explain what your code does, as it may not be obvious to all readers. Furthermore you should take another look at the formatted output of your code and correct the first line.